# Java test cases

Tags: java

```
import java.text.DecimalFormat;

public class Cylinder
{

// Instance Variables
private String label = "";
private double radius; 
private double height;
/**
*@param labelIn Represents label value
*@param radiusIn Represents radius value
*@param heightIn Represents height value
*/

public Cylinder(String labelIn, double radiusIn, double heightIn) 

{      
  label = labelIn.trim();
  radius = radiusIn;
  height = heightIn;
}

/**
*@return String representation of label. 
* Accepts no parameters and returns 
* a string representing the label field.
*/
public String getLabel()
{
  return label;
}
/**
* Takes string parameter and returns boolean.
*@param labelIn Command Line used
*@return checks to see if labelIn exist.
*/ 
public boolean setLabel(String labelIn)
{
  if (labelIn == null)
  {
     return false;
  }
  else 
  {
     label = labelIn.trim();
     return true;
  }
}
/**
*@return a method to display a double radius.
* Accepts no parameter and returns double representing 
* radius.
*/ 
public double getRadius()
{
  return radius;
}
/**
*@param radiusIn Command Line used.
* Accepts a double parameter, sets radius field, and
* returns nothing.
*/ 
public void setRadius(double radiusIn)
{ 
  radius = radiusIn;
}
/**
*@return a method to display a double height.
* Accepts no parameters and returns double
* representing the height field.
*/
public double getHeight()
{
  return height;
}
/**
*@param heightIn Command Line used.
* Accepts a double parameter, sets radius field, and 
* returns nothing.
*/ 
public void setHeight(double heightIn)
{ 
  height = heightIn;
}
/**
*@return displays diameter when method is called.
* Accepts no parameters and returns double value
* for diameter calculated using radius.
*/ 
public double diameter()
{
  return radius * 2;
}
/**
*@return displays circumference when method is called.
* Accepts no parameters and returns double value 
* for circumference calculated using Math.PI and radius.
*/ 
public double circumference()
{
  return Math.PI * radius * 2;
}
/**
*@return displays area when method is called.
* Accepts no parameters and returns double value
* for surface area calculated using Math.PI, radius, and height.
*/ 
public double area()
{
  return 2 * Math.PI * radius * radius + 2 * Math.PI * radius * height;
}
/**
*@return displays volume when method is called.
* Accepts no parameters and returns double value
* for volume calculated using Math.PI, radius, and height.
*/ 
public double volume()
{
  return Math.PI * radius * radius * height;
}
/**
*@return displays cylinder information.
* Returns a string containing the information about
* the cylinder object.
*/ 
public String toString()
{
  DecimalFormat fmt = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.0##");

  return   "\"" + label
           + "\" is a cylinder with radius = " +     fmt.format(getRadius())
           + " units and height = " + fmt.format(getHeight()) + " units," 
           + "\nwhich has diameter = " + fmt.format(diameter())  
           + " units, circumference = " + fmt.format(circumference()) 
           + " units,"
           + "\narea = " + fmt.format(area()) + " square units,"
           + " and volume = " + fmt.format(volume()) + " cubic units.";
 }
 }
```

I need to write test cases for each method but I'm not really sure how to do that. I tried this..

```
@Test public void getLabelTest() {
      Cylinder c = new String("Cyl");
```

But I get an `incompatible type error`. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: is this `Cylinder` is super to `String`?????

Comment: `String c = new Cylinder("test", 5, 5).getLabel();`

Comment: How would i write one for setLabel?

Comment: Your label would be _set_ by the constructor `("test"..)`

Comment: I've figured out how to write test cases for every method that is public void, but for public double, i keep getting "missing return statement" error.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the `@Test` annotation, I assume you are supposed to use JUnit testing.

Check [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/doc/cookbook/cookbook.htm) for a short overview how it is done.

You are trying to assign a String to your Cylinder, that's where the **incompatible type error** comes from. I think you are meant to use

```
Cylinder c = new Cylinder("Cyl", 1.0, 1.0); // label = "Cyl", radius = 1.0, height = 1.0
```

Generally you are creating your (JUnit)-Test in a separate java file called a *JUnit Test Case* and there you are going to create the single tests for your methods annotated with @Test.

Here is simple example how such a *JUnit Test Case* could look like (related to your setLabel-method):

```
import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;

public class JUnitTest {

    private Cylinder c;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // initializing Cylinder instance to work on
        c = new Cylinder("Cyl", 1.0, 1.0);
    }

    @Test
    public void setLabelTest() {
        // parameter is null, return value should be false
        assertFalse(c.setLabel(null));
        // parameter is NOT null, return value should be true
        assertTrue(c.setLabel("Foo"));
    }
}
```

Also check [Assert doc](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html) for the different assertions.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still having trouble with methods that are public double.  For example, getRadius. I keep getting a "missing return statement error"

Comment: @user5293736 Show me what you've tried and especially in what context you're receiving this error.

Comment: @Test public double getRadiusTest() {
      Cylinder c = new Cylinder("label", 0, 0);
      double d2 = c.getRadius();
      Assert.assertEquals("test3", d2, 7);
   }

Comment: You are initializing your Cylinder with a radius of 0, so d2 is 0. In this case your assertion is incorrect, it should look like: `Assert.assertEquals("test3", 0, d2);` Additionally your test-method shouldn't return double. Use `@Test public void getRadiusTest() {...}` instead.

Comment: @Test public void getRadiusTest() {
      Cylinder c = new Cylinder("l", 0, 0);
      double d1 = 0;
      Assert.assertEquals("test3", 0, d1);         Should this work? It compiles, but I get a runtime error which is "java.lang.AssertionError: Use assertEquals(expected, actual, delta) to compare floating-point numbers"

Comment: Since you want to test your getRadius() method of your Cylinder class you are supposed to use the method. `@Test 
 public void getRadiusTest() { 
  Cylinder c = new Cylinder("l", 0, 0); 
  Assert.assertEquals("test3", 0, c.getRadius());
 }` 0 is your expected value, since you set the radius to 0 in the constructor `new Cylinder(...)` and `c.getRadius()` is your actual value.

Comment: @user5293736 assertEquals(String, double, double) is deprecated, you should use `Assert.assertEquals("test3", 0, c.getRadius(), 0.0);` to compare double. (See [here](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28java.lang.String,%20double,%20double,%20double%29))

Comment: Thanks, it works now. So for setRadius would i do basically the same? And also "public double volume?" Sorry for the many questions

Comment: @user5293736 Yes, exactly. You just have to consider what the current return value of your method has to be. In case of `public double volume(..)` especially (for example).

Comment: @Test public void setRadiusTest() {
      Cylinder c = new Cylinder("sr", 1, 1);
      Assert.assertEquals("test4", 1, c.setRadius(), 1.0);
   }
   When i input this I get a compile time error "method setRadius in class Cylinder cannot be applied to given types;" I think i'm missing the return, etc.

Comment: @user5293736 It seems like your are lacking some basic java understanding. You should check up on methods and their return values. `c.setRadius(1.5); // setting radius to 1.5 Assert.assertEquals("test4", 1.5, c.getRadius(), 0.0); // checking if the radius is 1.5`